# Grapefruit and sugar gelatin like substance

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

More or less I am trying to figure out how this reaction occurred, so I can reproduce it.

On a plate I had an excess amount of sugar with a fair amount of grapefruit juice which was stuck to the plate. I filled the plate with water and left it for a little over 24 hours. When I finally came back to do the dishes, I poured the contents of the plate into the sink only to find that the bottom of the plate was covered in this slime very similar to clear gelatin. This slime was about as thick as honey, but was not sticky in any way, and was completely clear.

What could have caused this?

Comment: If the plate had mostly dried, it might have been a gel formed from the pectin in the grapefruit.  That's just a guess though.